# How to convert 'GradientDescentOptimizer' in TensorFlow 2.7

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I want to convert

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
train =  optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

this code to work in TensorFlow 2.7

```
import numpy as np

num_points = 1000

vectors_set = []
for i in range(num_points):
  x1 = np.random.normal(0.0, 0.55)
  y1= x1*1 + 0.3 + np.random.normal(0.0, 0.1)
  vectors_set.append([x1, y1])

x_data = [v[0] for v in vectors_set]
y_data = [v[1] for v in vectors_set]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(y_data, x_data, 'ro')
plt.show()

import tensorflow as tf

W = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
y = W * x_data + b

loss = tf.reduce_mean(y-y_data)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
train =  optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

and here is what I got

```
module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'GradientDescentOptimizer'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace
`tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)` ==> `tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)`

**Working code**

```
import numpy as np

num_points = 1000

vectors_set = []
for i in range(num_points):
  x1 = np.random.normal(0.0, 0.55)
  y1= x1*1 + 0.3 + np.random.normal(0.0, 0.1)
  vectors_set.append([x1, y1])

x_data = [v[0] for v in vectors_set]
y_data = [v[1] for v in vectors_set]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(y_data, x_data, 'ro')
plt.show()

import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

W = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
y = W * x_data + b

loss = tf.reduce_mean(y-y_data)
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
train =  optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

Comment: thank you so much. i was wandering looking for answer. now i can run this code in 2.X.

Comment: Glad that it worked. Can you accept and upvote the answer.